# Is it possible to use QueryView with EF Code-First?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

The title should be self explanatory. [QueryView](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/edm-queryviews-vs-defining-queries-and-read-only-views/) in [EDMX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716798.aspx) allows predefined projections and conditional queries. QueryView creates additional readonly mapping.

Example:

Suppose that we have `BlogPost` table which has `Title`, `ShortDescription` and `Content` columns. If we want to use `BlogPost` we will use directly this entity. If we want to show list of recent `BlogPosts` showing only titles and descriptions we will not want to load contents as well. One way is to use query with projection directly. Other way is to map this projection in EDMX (by using QueryView = reusable projection is part of your mapping) to new entity called `BlogPostInfo`. Then you can query your context for `BlogPostInfo` entities when showing list of blog posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it is possilbe to use QueryView if `DbContext` is generated from EDMX because in such case `DbContext` only wrapps mapping in EDMX. But it is not what I was looking for. Code first itself probably doesn't offer any QueryView equivalent so the best way is probably define reusable projection queries as methods directly on derived `DbContext` implementation.

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by "_so the best way is probably define reusable projection queries as methods directly on derived DbContext implementation._"